# Draw a circular SKSpriteNode with texture?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Is there a way to draw a circular SKSpriteNode with texture? Or alternatively, draw a SKShapeNode with texture?

Comment: You can just make the texture rounded, can't you?

Comment: The texture is actually selected by the users on the spot, so they can't be round.

Comment: What does "with texture" mean? There are several ways of creating a circular sprite.

Answer (score 3):

It is to consider that all images are rectangle/squares. What we see as round, is how we show colored pixels: what is outside the circle, is transparent and what is inside, is the colored part.

1. we need a circle
2. we texture it
3. we add it to the scene
4. we take back a new texture from this shape node that we just added to the scene
5. we make a new sprite using this new texture
6. we add the sprite to the scene

   ```
   let shape: SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
   shape.name = "shape"
   shape.lineWidth = 1 // this way we see that this is a circle
   shape.fillColor = .white // to see the true colors of our image
   //shape.strokeColor = .white
   //shape.glowWidth = 0
   shape.fillTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"myImage")
   shape.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y:200)
   self.addChild(shape)

   let newTexture: SKTexture = (self.view?.texture(from: self.childNode(withName: "shape")!))!
   let sprite: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: newTexture)
   self.addChild(sprite) 

   shape.removeFromParent()
   ```

Comment: You can create a texture with `shape` without adding it to a scene by `view?.texture(from: shape)`.